# Erro ao inserir no banco de dados Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, crud

Comecei a estudar um pouco sobre desenvolvimento web, mas tenho um problema ao tentar inserir na tabela. 
Apresenta um erro, quando clico num dps cadastrar, apresenta essa mensagem no browser :

```
 query("INSERT INTO nafcliente (nome,local) VALUES ('$nome' , '$local') ") or die ($mysqli->error); }
```

Essa seria minha index,fiz bem simples só para testar

html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
      <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
            <input type="text" name="local" placeholder="Digite seu endereço" />
            <input type="submit" name="Cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" />   
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Essa é minha página do process.php

```
<?php

$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost","root","","cad") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar'])){

    $nome= $_POST['nome'];
    $local= $_POST['local'];

    $mysqli-> query("INSERT INTO cliente (nome,local) VALUES ('$nome' , '$local') ") or 
    die ($mysqli->error);
}
```

Comment: Quando for inserir mais informação edite a pergunta e inclua direto nela

Comment: Pode deixar,valeu pelo aviso

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php


$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost","root","","cad") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));



if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar'])){

    $nome= $_POST['nome'];
    $local= $_POST['local'];

    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO cliente (nome,local) VALUES ('$nome' , '$local') ");
    if(!query){
      echo("error");
}
```

tenta assim, talvez esteja errado a minha parte, faz tempo que não mecho com php, porém eu vi um código meu que está assim , não custa tentar ;)

Comment: Opa,testei aqui...o erro no browser sumiu,mas nenhum registro aparece no banco

MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (A consulta demorou 0,0000 segundos.)

Answer (score -1):

Vejo que só no Query  `$mysqli-> query("SQL") or die ($mysqli->error);` que está faltando referenciar a conexão.

`$mysqli-> query($mysqli, "SQL") or die ($mysqli->error);`

E também na conexão deve ser `mysqli_connect` e não apenas `mysqli`

```
$mysqli= new mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","cad") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

**Proposta em Mysqli:**

```
<?php

$mysqli= mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","cad") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar'])){

    $nome= $_POST['nome'];
    $local= $_POST['local'];

mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO cliente (nome,local) VALUES ('$nome' , '$local') ") or 
die ($mysqli->error);
}}
```

Documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Está usando PDO né isso? Pra um sistema simples você pode simplificar e usar apenas mysqli que também é uma classe segura e bem parecida com a sintaxe que foi descontinuada.

Comment: Beleza vou testar essas dicas,obrigado

Comment: Mysqli_connect é muito bom e simples. uso em todas as minhas aplicações.

Comment: O erro no browser pelo menos sumiu,porém n encontro registro na tabela

Comment: Certo! Vou editar a resposta com uma proposta apenas com Mysqli.

Comment: Muito obrigado,velho

Comment: O browser exibe:

error);
}}

o que poderia ser?

Comment: Ah pq tem um } a mais. É só apagar uma.

Comment: Opa,muito obrigado pelos toques